# HPE Enable High-Efficiency Mode

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hp

I've been reading through the [HPE Common Slot Power Supply Documentation](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04111541&) and noticed "high-efficiency mode". It states you can enable it "via the server's ROM-based setup utility under System options -> Redundancy options".

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on this server, how do I activate high-efficiency mode?

Thank you!

Comment: "via the server's ROM-based setup utility" is BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Terrance's comment - it should be in BIOS if available. I have not confirmed this yet.